# What is this implement called and where can I get one?

Tags: bathroom, shower

In my shower there are two bumps meant to receive a square rod. I drew a picture as I don't know what they would be called. I want to put a rod in there, but I don't know if there is a special name for it and where I would get one.

[image]

Comment: Square towel bars like to get pulled of the wall. Buy one with a cylindrical rod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a towel bar. Usually they come with the "bumps" so you might have to buy both.

Comment: LOL @ "bumps" ?